# can sonar-runner be used under .net framework 3.5 or below?

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonar-runner

now i use sonar-runner2.4 (sonarqube is 5.1.2 ) to submit c# project. 
but my system is windows XP, only compatible with .net framework 3.5 and below.
The .net framework 4.5 or 4.6 can not be installed .

is there any way to use sonar-runner under XP to submit c# ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the sonar-runner cannot be used to analyze C# projects. You will have to use the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild and find a solution for the .NET Framework issue.

Note that you can run the SonarQube analysis of your project from any computer: It does not have to be your development machine nor the one on which your SonarQube server is running.